# Wrapping an Angular 2+ directive with another directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to reduce clutter in my (Angular 7) app by creating a directive which takes a simplified set of parameters (such as a user ID) and displays a `ng-bootstrap` popover.

I'd like the directive to work as similarly as possible to a normal ng-bootstrap popover, except that it's created using the custom directive instead. I know I could do something similar with a component, but I'm planning on using this directive on enough different elements that it wouldn't be feasible.

Is it possible to wrap directives like this in Angular 2+, and if so what would the best approach be to making this happen?

[I've created a StackBlitz with what I've created so far here:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsvpnt?file=src/app/custom.directive.ts)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[app-custom-directive]'
})
export class CustomDirective implements OnInit {
  private element: HTMLInputElement;


  @Input() parameter: string = 'Parameter';

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.element = elRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.element.onclick = () => {
      alert('This should open a popover containing the directive parameter "' + this.parameter + '". But how?')
    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First of all, you should never do the

```
this.element.onclick = () => {
```

Use ***@HostListener*** instead. It's angular-way to listen for events in angular on the Directives.

2) You really need a component here which will have a directive and the input you need.

3) I don't know if it will work but you can at least try to extend a `NgbPopover` directive:

```
  export class CustomDirective extends NgbPopover {
      // private element: HTMLInputElement;

      constructor(
        private _elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
        private _renderer: Renderer2,
        injector: Injector,
        componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        config: NgbPopoverConfig,
        private _ngZone: NgZone,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any
      ) {
        super(_elementRef, _renderer, injector, componentFactoryResolver, viewContainerRef, config, _ngZone, _document);
      }
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I just figured out that I can use an *attribute* component instead of an *element* component, so what I can do is basically `<div custom-component>` and then use `<ng-content>` to project the contents of that div into the component. Thanks to you I'm on the right track!